# ngFor while string is "something" is posible?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I need to show only a part of a list in a ngfor in this case only when id is 1.
How can I achive this?

```
while id==1

*ngFor="let item of list">{{item.value}}

this.list = [
      {id:1, value:1},
      {id:1, value:2},
      {id:1, value:3},
      {id:2, value:4},
      {id:2, value:5},
      {id:2, value:6}
  ];
```

Comment: `this.filteredList = this.list.filter(e => e.id === 1);`, and now you use ngFor to display every element of filteredList

Comment: Please add any code/approach that you've already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `*ngIf` statement within the `*ngFor` statement. Something like:

```
<div *ngFor='let item of list'>
    <div *ngIf='item.id==1'>
        {{item.value}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a working stackblitz example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skf1wq

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, Just you have to check `data.id == 1` while you execute `ngFor` in HTML`

```
<div *ngFor="let data of list">
    // Hear you have to check with *ngIf
    <div *ngIf="data.id == 1">
        {{data.value}}          // It will print only when data id is 1
    </div>
</div>
```